# How can I manipulate an Array?

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array

```
arr[]={7,5,-8,3,4};
```

And I have to update the same array to

```
arr[]={7,12,4,7,11};
```

my code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sumArr(int *arr, int size);

void main()
{

    int arr[] = { 7,5,-8,3,4 };
    int i, size, res = 0;

    printf("Enter Size Of The Array:");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    res = sumArr(arr, size);

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", res);
    }

  }


int sumArr(int *arr, int size)
{

        int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
      arr[i+1]+= arr[i];

        printf("  %d  \n", arr[i + 1]);
    }

    return arr[i+1];
}
```

The output should be:  `7,12,4,7,11`
But in my code, the output is:   `12,4,7,11,-858993449,58196502,58196502,58196502,58196502,58196502`

Any hints?
I can use auxiliary functions for input and output arrays, will it help?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask for the size of the array when you already know it.  It has 5 elements, be sure to type "5" instead of "10".  Don't ask, or realloc().

Comment: You are right. it is a preparation for dynamic array. (IF it makes sense). and I did press 5...

Comment: `arr[i+1]` goes out of bounds on the last iteration of the loop, and in the return statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code:

- You need to stop the summing loop once `i+1` reaches the end of the array
- Your code knows the size; there is no need to read it from end-user
- You need to print the value of `res` once, rather than printing it in a loop
- You should consider moving the printing portion of the program into `main` from `sumArray`.

The modifications are very straightforward:

```
int sumArr(int *arr, int size) {
    // Stop when i+1 reaches size; no printing
    for (int i = 0; i+1 < size; i++) {
        arr[i+1]+= arr[i];
    }
    return arr[size-1];
}
```

Printing in the `main`:

```
printf("sum=%d\n", res);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("arr[%d] = %d\n", i, arr[i]);
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/5Do9bT)

Comment: I really appreciate your help! but why return arr[size-1]?

Comment: @AndrewM To avoid "bleeding" the value of `i` to outside the scope of the loop.